# How to document response schema for Django REST Framework documentaion?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, documentation

I'm documenting a custom endpoint using default DRF documentation API. The output of the endpoint is quite complex and I need a pretty way to display it to the frontend-developers in documentation API. Current solution is to use method's docstring which is not that pretty.

There is a clean way to describe *input parameters* using `schema`, but I'm unable to find examples to describe schema for the output.

There is screenshot in the official documentation that indicates that it is possible (note a `response schema` at the picture), but unfortunately no example.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same functionality but it seems like most of this response stuff is auto-generated with little control over it. E.g., my setup kept insisting that all my POSTs must return a 201 and no way to specify a custom response body, just some object that it decided this POST is creating.

Ended up using `drf-yasg` instead, it was super-easy to get started and [specify responses](https://drf-yasg.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_spec.html), e.g.:
`user_response = openapi.Response('response description', UserSerializer)`